# While calculating KL divergence by python with a specific P(x) as reference distribution how to define input values p and q?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to implement KL divergence and I want to use P(x) as a reference distribution with which I want to compare my model's distribution. How to get the histogram from reference distribution P(x)?

```py
def P(x):
    return ((32/(math.pi)**2)*(x)**2*np.exp(-(4/math.pi)*(x)**2))

x = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
n,bins,patches = ax.hist(x,bins=10,density=True)
```

For calculating KL divergence I have defined the function

```py
def KL(p,q):
    KL_list =[]
    for i in range(p):
        val= p*np.log(q /p)
        KL_list.append(val)
    KL_list=-1*np.sum(np.array(KL_list))
    return KL_list
```

Now In order to call function KL(p,q) I have to define p and q so what will be value of p and q in my case?

Answer (score -1):

As I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687458/how-to-calculate-probabilities-using-numpy-histogram-and-then-use-it-for-calcula/57692592#57692592), the following is my solution for the mutual information computation (which is basically KL):

```
def mutual_information(x, y, sigma=1):
    bins = (256, 256)
    # histogram
    hist_xy = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)[0]

    # smooth it out for better results
    ndimage.gaussian_filter(hist_xy, sigma=sigma, mode='constant', output=hist_xy)

    # compute marginals
    hist_xy = hist_xy + EPS # prevent division with 0
    hist_xy = hist_xy / np.sum(hist_xy)
    hist_x = np.sum(hist_xy, axis=0)
    hist_y = np.sum(hist_xy, axis=1)

    # compute mi
    mi = (np.sum(hist_xy * np.log(hist_xy)) - np.sum(hist_x * np.log(hist_x)) - np.sum(hist_y * np.log(hist_y)))
    return mi
```