# How to calculate probabilities using numpy.histogram and then use it for calculating KL divergence?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability

In the following code, the `density=True` returns probability density function at each bin. Now if have to calculate P(x), can I say that `hist` is showing probabilities? For example if the first bin's mean value is 0.5 can I say that at x=0.5 probability is hist[0] ? I have to use KL divergence which uses P(x).

```
x = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,])
hist,bin_edges= np.histogram(x,bins=10,density=True)
```

Comment: Since probability is the integral over the propability density, the probability for a value to be in the `n`th bin is `hist[n]*np.diff(bin_edges)[n]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `density=True`, `NumPy` returns a *probability density function* (lets say `p`). Theoretically speaking, `p(0.5) = 0` because the probability is defined as the area under the PDF curve. You can read more details about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). So, if you want to the compute probability you will have to define desired range and sum up all PDF values in this range.

For the KL, I can share my solution for the mutual information computation (which is basically KL):

```
def mutual_information(x, y, sigma=1):
    bins = (256, 256)
    # histogram
    hist_xy = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)[0]

    # smooth it out for better results
    ndimage.gaussian_filter(hist_xy, sigma=sigma, mode='constant', output=hist_xy)

    # compute marginals
    hist_xy = hist_xy + EPS # prevent division with 0
    hist_xy = hist_xy / np.sum(hist_xy)
    hist_x = np.sum(hist_xy, axis=0)
    hist_y = np.sum(hist_xy, axis=1)

    # compute mi
    mi = (np.sum(hist_xy * np.log(hist_xy)) - np.sum(hist_x * np.log(hist_x)) - np.sum(hist_y * np.log(hist_y)))
    return mi
```

**EDIT:**
KL *could* be computed like this (please note that i did not test this!):

```
def kl(x, y, sigma=1):
    # histogram
    hist_xy = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)[0]

    # smooth it out for better results
    ndimage.gaussian_filter(hist_xy, sigma=sigma, mode='constant', output=hist_xy)

    # compute marginals
    hist_xy = hist_xy + EPS # prevent division with 0
    hist_xy = hist_xy / np.sum(hist_xy)
    hist_x = np.sum(hist_xy, axis=0)
    hist_y = np.sum(hist_xy, axis=1)

    kl = -np.sum(hist_x * np.log(hist_y / hist_x ))
    return kl
```

Also, for the best result, you should compute `sigma` with some heuristics, for example [A rule-of-thumb bandwidth estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).

Comment: @carobnodrov for the KL divergence should I use y-axis values of my histogram ? KL divergence measures difference b/w two distribution. If I choose each bin's center(on x-axis) as x value suppse it is 0.5  and then calculate  reference distribution (Poisson or any other)  for x=0.5. IS that how we proceed in KL divergence? I'm confused that does the formula of KL divergence uses the y-axis value ? Or should I need to calculate probabilities?

Comment: @jerry For the KL you should not use 2D histogram in this case (or you could and then just sum marginal probabilities). I will try to edit my question to include a solution for KL.

Comment: On wikipiedia they have used an example to solve KL divergence. They showed x-axis as bin number and y-axis as probability. I'm really confused in my Question I defined x as input so what will be the corresponding y values for substituting in KL divergence?

Comment: Please check if my edit helps you. KL measures "distance" between two probabilities. So `x` and `y` are the two probabilities.